# How to conditionally redirect depending on login name in ASP.NET C# framework 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET with C# on the back  framework 4

It comes with user register/login/logout mechanism.

on load of the default.aspx page I would like to redirect the users: user1 and user2 to default2.aspx and the rest of the users to default3.asp

I would not like to use cookies, but using a session is acceptable.

something like:

```
if (username == "user1" || username == "user2")  
{
Response.Redirect("defualt2.aspx"); 
} 
else 
{
Response.Redirect("default3.aspx"); 
}
```

Comment: sorry I answered one thing but I misunderstood your question. I thought your were looking for a way to get the user name. What exactly do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (User.Identity.Name)
    {
        case "user2":
        case "user1":
            Response.Redirect("defualt2.aspx");
            break;
        default:
            Response.Redirect("default3.aspx");
            break;
    }
 }
```

However you might want to use [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer.aspx) instead of Response.Redirect, if you don't want the address to change in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

`User.Identity.Name` from `System.Web`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Page.User.Identity.Name == "user1" || Page.User.Identity.Name == "user2")  
{
    Response.Redirect("defualt2.aspx"); 
} 
else 
{
    Response.Redirect("default3.aspx"); 
}
```

That should do it as long as you're within an aspx code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Wow!  There are tons of ways to do this.  When the user logs in you could set a session variable identifying the user and then use your code above but instead check for username == Session["user1"].ToString() but that code is not recommended because now you are locking yourself into hardcoding the username into the code.  Next would be to put the username into the web.config so it could be changed easily but again, not acceptable.

It sounds like you are probably doing this for security reasons.  If that is the case, you should look into the Role Provider that is already part of the Framework.  This provides you with a mechanism to place users in specific roles and then based on that role allow or disallow users on certain pages based on a decorator above the class.

I would not use the code you have posted in any circumstance.  It is not good practice to hard-code usernames into code.

Comment: It's okay, it was just a simplified example, which is solved now. Thanks anyways.